# Filtering strings from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to filter strings from an array. For example I have five strings

1. adcfd
2. adjnrj
3. amlkc
4. nfldkm
5. cslkls

If I want to create a new array that contains the filtered array, e.g. it starts with 'ad' it will create an array with two elements [adcfd, adjnrj]

or if it starts with 'a' we will get an array with three elements [adcfd, adjnrj, amlkc]

The only thing in my mind is to compare each character from all the strings until we get two 'trues' then we can end the loop.

If there is any function that I don't know, can I give any suggestions?

Comment: Might want to look into [regular expressions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (regex) if you plan on creating a filter system.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and see if you find some way to determine if a string starts with another string.

Comment: @user306856 Do you know you can accept solution which you think it helps you by checking the tick beside it??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [startsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) method of `String` class in java. For example,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Str = new String("Welcome to StackOverflow");

    System.out.print("Return Value :" );
    System.out.println(Str.startsWith("Welcome") );

    System.out.print("Return Value :" );
    System.out.println(Str.startsWith("StackOverflow") );
}
```

It prints:

```
Return Value :true
Return Value :false
```

**Edit**: Previously i didn't give straightforward answer to OP's question as i thought OP will try from my given example. Since others have already shared their answer, i am sharing a simple code snippet that will provide OP the desired output.

```
String[] strings = {"adcfd", "adjnrj", "amlkc", "nfldkm", "cslkls"};
String prefix = "ad";
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String str : strings) {
    if (str.startsWith(prefix)) {
        result.add(str);
    }
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

It prints:

```
[adcfd, adjnrj]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way in Java 8.

Since [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) API is now available to Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String[] stringArray = {"adcfd", "adjnrj", "amlkc", "nfldkm", "cslkls"};
   List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
   Object[] result = myList.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("ad")).toArray();
   for(Object obj : result){
      System.out.println(obj);
   }
 }
```

Note this will work only in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] strings = {"adcfd", "adjnrj", "amlkc", "nfldkm", "cslkls"};
    String prefix = "ad";
    String[] result = null;

    // Use String#startsWith
    result = Stream.of(strings).filter(str -> str.startsWith(prefix))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()).toArray(new String[0]);
    Stream.of(result).forEach(System.out::println); //-> adjnrj adcfd

    // Use String#matches (with regexp)
    result = Stream.of(strings).filter(str -> str.matches("^" + prefix + ".*$"))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()).toArray(new String[0]);
    Stream.of(result).forEach(System.out::println);  //-> adjnrj adcfd
```

Comment: Why do you use `toSet()` instead of `toList()`?

Comment: @LukeLee I didn't consider much, just tried to remove duplicated items. `toList` is also fine if no need to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can *sort String* first then you can get all *matched String* without compare all string element.

an alternative code segment:

```
public class Demo {
public List<String> test(String[] strs,String filter){
    List<String> res = new LinkedList<>();
    Arrays.sort(strs);
    for(String str:strs){
        if(str.startsWith(filter)){
            res.add(str);
            continue;
        }
        if(str.compareTo(filter)>0){
            return res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

 public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] strs = {"adcfd","adjnrj","amlkc","nfldkm","cslkls"};
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    String filter = "a";
    System.out.println(demo.test(strs, filter));
 }
}
```

output:

```
[adcfd, adjnrj, amlkc]
```